# stuck in understanding a part of code

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is a problem in this link:   http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/9204

I couldn't solve it so i decided to read the [answer](https://github.com/anudeep2011/programming/blob/master/MKTHNUM.cpp).
Here is the solution:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#define sz size()
#define pb push_back
#define rep(i,n) for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
#define fd(i,a,b) for(int i=a; i>=b; i--)

#define N 111111
struct node
{
    int count;
    node *left, *right;
    node(int count, node *left, node *right):
        count(count), left(left), right(right) {}

    node* insert(int l, int r, int w);
};

node *null = new node(0, NULL, NULL); //see line 135

node * node::insert(int l, int r, int w)
{
    if(l <= w && w < r)
    {
        // With in the range, we need a new node
        if(l+1 == r)
        {
            return new node(this->count+1, null, null);
        }

        int m = (l+r)>>1;

        return new node(this->count+1, this->left->insert(l, m, w), this->right->insert(m, r, w));
    }

    // Out of range, we can use previous tree node.
    return this;
}

int query(node *a, node *b, int l, int r, int k)
{
    if(l+1 == r)
    {
        return l;
    }

    int m = (l+r)>>1;
    int count = a->left->count - b->left->count;
    if(count >= k)
        return query(a->left, b->left, l, m, k);

    return query(a->right, b->right, m, r, k-count);
}

int a[N], RM[N];
node *root[N];

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);

    map <int, int> M;
    rep(i, n)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        M[a[i]];
    }

    int maxi = 0;    
    for(map <int, int> :: iterator it = M.begin(); it != M.end(); it++)
    {
        M[it->first] = maxi;
        RM[maxi] = it->first;
        maxi++;
    }

    null->left = null->right = null;
    rep(i, n)
    {
        // Build a tree for each prefix using segment tree of previous prefix
        root[i] = (i == 0 ? null : root[i-1])->insert( 0, maxi, M[a[i]] );
    }

    while(m--)
    {
        int u, v, k;
        scanf("%d%d%d", &u, &v, &k);
        u--; v--;

        int ans = query(root[v], (u==0?null:root[u-1]), 0, maxi, k);
        printf("%d\n", RM[ans]);
    }
}
```

there are somethings I cant understand in this code:

1. what does `M[a[i]];` mean in the first loop of the main function?!
2. what does `count` do in the node struct?!

I understood it uses segment tree but it is difficult to understand the solution.

I would be happy if anyone can help me :)
thanks in advance

Comment: Wow, this code is awful.

Comment: Please make sure your question is self-contained. While it is entirely appropriate to link the place you got the code / exercise, you should summarize the pertinent points here and only give the link as suplementary reference.

Comment: @Deduplicator The link is just his motivation for downloading the answer, his question is just about the code he posted.

Comment: @Barmar: Doesn't mean he shouldn't summarize what the code should do.

Comment: @Deduplicator I went to the contest page, I couldn't understand the task. :)

Comment: The code leaks memory like a sieve.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That's exaggerating it. And sometimes, just not bothering to free memory is a valid optimization and simplification strategy. But those macros... and I mean every single one.

Comment: @Deduplicator -  Yes about the memory leaks, but more often than not, it leads to bad habits that are hard to break.   Anyway, it seems that unfortunately, those macros are becoming popular:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256207/time-limit-of-c-code

Comment: @Paul Gaah. Don't link to that without a disclaimer not to look while you are eating.

Comment: @Barmar: Happily, someone there linked the same task on SPOJ. They at least managed to write an understandable description: http://www.spoj.com/problems/MKTHNUM/

Comment: It looks like `count` indicates how many levels from the root a particular node is.  `M[a[i]]` is used to initialize the map with keys that are all of the values in the input array - the associated values for each map element will be 0 at this point. They get properly initialized in the next loop with `M[it->first] = maxi;` which sets the value for each map element to it's 'rank'. For other readers of this question, an explanation of the core code can be found here: http://blog.anudeep2011.com/persistent-segment-trees-explained-with-spoj-problems/  It's an interesting problem & solution.

Answer (score 4):

1. `M[a[i]]` simply tries to access that element of the map. This causes the element to be created with a default value. It does this so that the second loop will see all the elements of the map.
2. I'm not totally sure, but I think `count` is a measure of the depth of the tree. Every time it makes a new node, it increments it from the node where new node is inserted.